# eslint --fix throwing error after sorting imports

Tags: reactjs, next.js, eslint, lint

I'm using `eslint-plugin-import` to sort imports in my Next.js project. This is my configuration:

**.eslintrc.js**

```
module.exports = {
  extends: [
    'next',
    'prettier',
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
  ],
  plugins: ['react', 'import'],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  rules: {
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': 'off',
    'react/prop-types': 'off',
    'react/react-in-jsx-scope': 'off',
    'react/jsx-uses-react': 'error',
    'react/jsx-uses-vars': 'error',
    'prefer-const': 'error',
    '@next/next/no-html-link-for-pages': 'off',
    'react/jsx-key': 'off',
    'import/order': [
      'error',
      {
        groups: ['builtin', 'external', 'internal'],
        pathGroups: [
          {
            pattern: 'react',
            group: 'external',
            position: 'before',
          },
        ],
        pathGroupsExcludedImportTypes: ['react'],
        'newlines-between': 'always-and-inside-groups',
        alphabetize: {
          order: 'asc',
          caseInsensitive: true,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

When I run `eslint --fix`, it correctly sorts my imports; `React` packages first, then external packages from `node_modules`, then internal. As an example, one of my project's pages:

```
import { type Tutors } from '@prisma/client';
import type { GetServerSideProps, NextPage } from 'next';
import { NextSeo } from 'next-seo';

import { Heading, Submenu } from '@vero/ui';
import { getSession } from 'lib/auth/session';
import { prisma } from 'lib/prisma';
import { TutorProfile } from 'modules/tutors/components/tutor-profile/TutorProfile';
import { tutorSubmenu } from 'modules/tutors/lib/utils';

type EditProfilePageProps = NextPage & {
  tutor: Tutors;
};

const Profile = ({ tutor }: EditProfilePageProps) => {
  return (
    <>
      <NextSeo title="Edit Profile" />
      <div className="container my-12 flex flex-col gap-6 lg:flex-row">
        <Submenu orientation="vertical" items={tutorSubmenu} />
        <div className="flex flex-1 grow flex-col gap-6">
          <Heading tag="h3" className="my-12">
            Your Profile
          </Heading>
          <TutorProfile tutor={tutor} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Profile;

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({ req }) => {
  const session = await getSession({ req });

  const tutor = await prisma.tutors.findFirst({
    where: {
      userId: session?.user.id,
    },
  });

  return {
    props: {
      tutor,
    },
  };
};
```

Again, this been auto-sorted this way. However, when I open the page in VS Code, I'm still getting an error:

```
`next` import should occur after import of `modules/tutors/lib/utils`
```

From the error, it's seeing `next`, which is an external package from `node_modules` and my `modules`, which is an internal directory from my root, as being part of the same import group. I don't understand why, as it's auto-sorting them correctly. What can I do to fix this and get rid of the error?